# Selected audio won't load in Chrome, but will in Firefox, Safari

Tags: google-chrome, audio

The following link demonstrates my problem.  It hosts two audio files.  Both appear in Firefox or Safari, but only the first appears in Chrome; the second is grayed out.  https://www.msu.edu/~brown202/31et/test1.html

Comment: They both work for me, Chrome 14.0.814.0 m. What version are you using?

Comment: 13.0.782.218 m doesn't work for me.

Comment: is it always the second player, or is it to do with the file being played?  what happens if you swap the file orders in the test?

Comment: Order doesn't seem to matter:
https://www.msu.edu/~brown202/31et/chrome_bug_2.html

The bug only happens with certain files.  It's consistent -- it keeps happening with the same files -- but I can't find any meaningful difference between the ones that work and the ones that don't.  When I download them using FTP and play them from my hard drive, they all work fine.  And they were all generated at the same time, using the same Mathematica code.  I've tried regenerating them, but the problem persists, with the same files.

Comment: My Chrome is 13.0.782.218, which it says is up to date.  14 is the beta, correct?